# Using number of items in a stream to control the ability to add new items

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

I have a working bloc using rxdart that populates a ListView using a StreamBuilder in my app. The data is sourced from a service I've written for a Firebase database.

I'm trying to figure out how to control whether a user can add additional items to the database based on the number of items they've already added. For example, under certain circumstances, they can add as many as they like, but under other circumstances, they can only add 1.  I have the piece working to add items already.

My objective is to hide/show the widget I'm using that has a GestureDetector that, when tapped, navigates to the screen to add a new item to the database.

My approach was to add a new BehaviorSubject that is populated when the Stream of existing items is populated. My ListView is built using the personsByUserID stream.

```
final _personCount = BehaviorSubject<int>();

...

// getters
Stream<int> get personCount => _personCount.stream;

...

// setters
Function(int) get changePersonCount => _personCount.sink.add;

...

Stream<List<Person>> personsByUserId(String userId) {
    Stream<List<Person>> people = db.fetchPersonsByUserId(userId);

    int personCount = 0;

    people.toList().then((value) => personCount = value.length);

    changePersonCount(personCount);

    return people;
  }

...
```

I then have a StreamBuilder on my screen based on the personCount that hides/shows a child widget based on the value.

The problem is that the resulting value of personCount is never more than zero despite having more than 1 record in the database.

I know I'm doing something wrong here and I've probably taken the wrong approach, but am at a loss as to how to achieve what I'm trying to do.  Any suggestions?

Comment: `toList()` is returning a Future and you set `personCount` once that Future completes. I suspect the issue is `changePersonCount()` is reached before the Future completes and is therefore always zero. Move the changePersonCount call to inside the then() so it is triggered once the Future is complete.

Comment: @amugofjava - Thanks, I've changed it to have the changePersonCount inside the 'then' block but when I debug it never even seems to enter the block.

Comment: Can you show your code on how you're getting ```personCount```

Comment: For reference, I did it [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55261110/flutter-how-to-show-number-of-items-in-list) instead.